# How to handle GetStatusAsync Final Continuation Token never null?

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

Using .net core 2 in azure.
The code below queries the azure taskhub *instances* table for durable instances, but its last continuation token is never null. anyone know how to handle this?

The table has 184 items.

1. first loop returns 100, and provides a continuation token.
2. second loop returns 84, and provides a continuation token of "bnVsbA=="
3. This final token causes the loop to repeat from start, infinitely.

```cs
OrchestrationStatusQueryCondition cond = new OrchestrationStatusQueryCondition();
cond.CreatedTimeFrom = System.DateTime.UnixEpoch; // set date range
System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource source = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource();           
do
{
   var workers = await client.GetStatusAsync(cond, source.Token);
   cond.ContinuationToken = workers.ContinuationToken;
} 
while(cond.ContinuationToken != null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that this is a bug in azure functions

see: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/1174

I will have to test for != "*bnVsbA==*"

And probably != null for when its fixed.

Comment: This bug should be fixed in release [2.2.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask/2.2.0) of the extension.